# running ruby on rails in virtual box debian instanz

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, virtual-machine, virtualbox, portforwarding

my host system is a windows 8.1 system
there i've running a debian 7 vm in virtual box.

I've created a new Ruby on Rails project and started the server. Server starts properly and listen on port 3000

[image]

So i added a port forwarding rule in virtual box for this port

[image]

But now when I try to reach 127.0.0.1:3333 from my host got an error page not found.

Is there something to look at?

Comment: Try set  bridged your network in virtual box. After that your virtual box is like a another machine, in debian type ifconfig and find your ip then from windows  navigate to your_ip:3000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when starting your server, use `sudo rails server --binding=0.0.0.0`